# MVC 5 - Each iteration of foreach loop creates new radio button group. How can I access results in the controller?

Tags: c#, razor, foreach, asp.net-mvc-5, radio-button

I'm creating an MVC 5 web app. 
In the view I am creating a table and iterating through a foreach loop to create a row with 3 radio buttons in each row, each row being a radio button group.
The radio buttons are all pre-populated.

After I hit submit, I need to get the value of each group of radio buttons to use in the Controller.

**Problematic code from the view**

```
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Submit", "Home"))
        {
            <table>
                <tr><td>Application</td><td>Direct Debit only</td><td>Credit and Debit</td><td>Neither</td></tr>
                @{
                    int i = 0;

                    foreach (var app in Model.Applications)
                    {
                        i++;
                        string appCardType = "app" + i;
                        <tr>
                            <td>@app.Value.Name</td>
                            <td><input type="radio" name="@appCardType" @(app.Value.CardType.ToString() == "DebitOnly" ? "checked" : "" ) /></td>
                            <td><input type="radio" name="@appCardType" @(app.Value.CardType.ToString() == "CreditAndDebit" ? "checked" : "" ) /></td>
                            <td><input type="radio" name="@appCardType" @(app.Value.CardType.ToString() == "Neither" ? "checked" : "" ) /></td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                }
            </table>

            <input type="submit" value="Apply Settings" />
        }
```

**the (currently empty) controller**

```
    public ActionResult Submit()
    {


        return View();
    }
```

Anyone know how I can access the data provided by the user in the controller?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so after enlisting the help of another developer there was actually a super easy solution. Not sure if its "good code", but I'll paste my solution below.

**In the View,** I added a value attribute to each of the radio buttons. I did originally try using the Id attribute but that just did nothing.

```
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Submit", "Home"))
        {
            <table>
                <tr><td>Application</td><td>Direct Debit only</td><td>Credit and Debit</td><td>Neither</td></tr>
                @{
                    int i = 0;

                    foreach (var app in Model.Applications)
                    {
                        i++;
                        string appCardType = "app" + i;
                        <tr>
                            <td>@app.Value.Name</td>
                            <td><input type="radio" name="@appCardType" value="1" @(app.Value.CardType.ToString() == "DebitOnly" ? "checked" : "" ) /></td>
                            <td><input type="radio" name="@appCardType" value="2" @(app.Value.CardType.ToString() == "CreditAndDebit" ? "checked" : "" ) /></td>
                            <td><input type="radio" name="@appCardType" value="3" @(app.Value.CardType.ToString() == "Neither" ? "checked" : "" ) /></td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                }
            </table>

            <input type="submit" value="Apply Settings" />
        }
```

**In the Controller,** I then returned everything in the form (which was just the radio buttons) using FormCollection.

```
    public ActionResult Submit(FormCollection fm)
    {
        string Allpayments = Request.Form["app1"];
        string Callpay = Request.Form["app2"];
        string ThinGateway = Request.Form["app3"];
        string IVR = Request.Form["app4"];
        string TextPay = Request.Form["app5"];
        string SMSEngine = Request.Form["app6"];
        string AndroidMobileApp = Request.Form["app7"];
        string IOSMobileApp = Request.Form["app8"];
        string WindowsMobileApp = Request.Form["app9"];

        return View();
    }
```

This works and was pretty simple.

Comment: _Not sure if its "good code"_ - No! its dreadful code. Create a view model representing what you need in the view. Use strongly typed `HtmlHelper` methods to generate your view and post back your model (never use `ForCollection`). You need to go to the MVC site and work through the tutorials to understand the basics.

Comment: The main problem with this approach is that you gotta maintain the exact order in which the items are rendered; if in any case, there is a change in order, then the entire logic goes wrong and this will end up in maintenance nightmare.

Comment: Ok, taken into account. I'm still an apprentice and was given a pretty tight timescale on this project and haven't done MVC before. Once I've finished the project I intend to get an experienced developer to go through my code with me and apply best practices and good coding standards to it so I can see how I SHOULD have done things. 

P.S. You would probably have a stroke if you saw the rest of my code....

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your Model is as below:

```
 public class Application
 {
    public List<CardType> Applications { get; set; }

    public List<CardType> SelectedCardTypes { get; set; }
  }

 public class CardType
 {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
 }
```

Adding some dummy values in Index action:

```
 public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var vm = new Application();
        vm.Applications = new List<CardType>
       {
           new CardType {Value = "DebitOnly", Name = "Card 1" },
           new CardType {Value = "CreditAndDebit", Name = "Card 2" },
           new CardType {Value = "DebitOnly", Name = "Card 3" },
           new CardType {Value = "CreditAndDebit", Name = "Card 4" },
           new CardType {Value = "Neither", Name = "Card 5" },
           new CardType {Value = "DebitOnly", Name = "Card 6" },
           new CardType {Value = "Neither", Name = "Card 7" },
       };
        return View(vm);
    }
```

And your View:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Submit", "Home"))
 {
  <table>
      <tr>
       <td>Application</td><td>Direct Debit only</td><td>Credit and          Debit</td><td>Neither</td></tr>
    @{
        int i = 0;

        foreach (var app in Model.Applications)
        {

           // string appCardType = "cardType" + i;
            <tr>
                <td>@app.Name
                <input type="hidden" name="SelectedCardTypes[@i].Name" value="@app.Name" />
                </td>

                <td>
                <input type="radio" name="SelectedCardTypes[@i].Value" value="DebitOnly"  @(app.Value.ToString() == "DebitOnly" ? "checked" : "" ) /></td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="SelectedCardTypes[@i].Value" value="CreditAndDebit" @(app.Value.ToString() == "CreditAndDebit" ? "checked" : "" ) /></td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="SelectedCardTypes[@i].Value" value="Neither" @(app.Value.ToString() == "Neither" ? "checked" : "" ) /></td>
            </tr>
            i++;
        }
    }
</table>

        <input type="submit" value="Apply Settings" />
        }
```

Now if you submit, you will get a collection of CardType with corresponding Name and selected type in post method:

```
  [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Submit(Application application)
    {

        return View();
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Or you could reuse  public List<CardType> Applications { get; set; } itself and remove public List<CardType> SelectedCardTypes { get; set; }. Only change would be -> in .cshtml, change all SelectedCardTypes[@i] to Applications[@i]

Comment: Hi Developer, I'm sure your code would've worked fine, but I neglected to provide my model etc so the assumptions you made were wrong. Nevertheless, thank-you for taking the time to help!

Comment: @BrendanElding no problem...I never thought the items in collection would be fixed; I was thinking of generic solution. The secret behind model binding in MVC from form data is the 'name' attribute of form element. And when it comes to collections, the name should be PropertyName[index] for model binding to happen from form data.